# Report: error Traceback (most recent calls last)

Tags: error

there seems to be no answers for the error "Traceback (most recent calls last)" in blender 2.8. Reinstalling blender doesnt fix the problem. this error occurs by just left clicking in the viewport or when importing images into textures and backgrounds. It ruins blender. I have no idea how this has happened.

this is the error:
[image]

I do not want to install a new version of blender at the moment so that is out of the option. Please help. This error is really annoying. This must have something to do with a file directory but i am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set File > Defaults to  "Factory Settings"

Comment: thanks sooo much! that fixed it! It kinda feels obvious thinking about it now. Could you make that an answer so I can make the question answered and upvote you?

Comment: All python errors are preceded by _"Traceback (most recent calls last"_   The error would appear to be a context path being wrong either in a panel or keymap having the 3d view context instead of properties.  The latter has `context.space_data.context` the former doesn't.  If you are happy resetting everything back to factory defaults cool.

Comment: Yes. I did not save any presets or alter the default blender module so it would have not effected me. I would be happy to see alternatives that could be applied to solving this error as well however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert to Factory settings.

Set File > Defaults to "Factory Settings"

Answer (score -1):

Usually it will go away by itself.